# sql запрос на добавление нескольких объектов

Tags: sql, postgresql

База данных: Postgres 
Я добавляю данные несколькими запросами:

```
INSERT INTO "role" ("id", "name") VALUES (1, 'guest');
INSERT INTO "role" ("id", "name") VALUES (2, 'user');
INSERT INTO "role" ("id", "name") VALUES (3, 'admin');
```

Можно ли сделать тоже самое используя только один оператор *INSERT*?

Answer (score 3):

Да, postgresql [позволяет](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/sql-values) использовать множественные значения в values.

```
INSERT INTO "role" ("id", "name")
VALUES (1, 'guest'), (2, 'user'), (3, 'admin');
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно. Используя стандартный синтаксис:

```
INSERT INTO "role" ("id", "name") VALUES (1, 'guest'), (2, 'user'), (3, 'admin');
```

А для добавления большого числа строк (сотни) лучше использовать [команду `COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)